# What is behind the ‘@’ sign in @angular or @types?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to understand what is behind the ‘@’ sign when I see import statements like below:

```
Import { Injectable } from ‘@angular/core’;
```

Or npm cli commands like below:

```
npm -install –save @types/lodash
```

The statements or commands are working fine for me, I just want to learn what is happening behind the scene of the @ sign.

Is this '@' a TypeScript feature? or a NPM thing?

A pointer to an in-depth online documentation would be a great help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a NPM thing called `scoped packages`. Here is the [official doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages):

> Scopes are like namespaces for npm modules. If a package's name begins
>   with @, then it is a scoped package. The scope is everything in
>   between the @ and the slash.

All scoped packages are stored inside the folder that begins with `@`. For example, all Angular packages are stored inside the `@angular` folder in `node_modules`, whereas if there was no `@` scoped identifier and you used `angular/core` and `angular/compiler` you would have separate folder for each package. And the same holds for `@types` package.

> How TypeScript import statement recognizes that or integrates with the
>   '@'?

The `require` function that is used by `node` can traverse `node_modules` folder if you use forward slash in the path and it's not limited to scoped packages:

```
node_modules
   a
      b
         index.js
         module.exports = 3;

m.js
   console.log(require('a/b')); // logs 3
```

Typescript compiler uses node's `statSync` function under the hood to check the folder:

```
function fileSystemEntryExists(path, entryKind) {
    try {
        var stat = _fs.statSync(path);
        switch (entryKind) {
            case 0 /* File */: return stat.isFile();
            case 1 /* Directory */: return stat.isDirectory();
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and naturally this function treats forward slash as a path separator. When resolving path typescript compiler prepends `node_modules` to the path if [NODE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node) module resolution strategy is set.

Comment: Thank you for help. How TypeScript import statement recognizes that or integrates with the '@'?

Answer (score 3):

It's an NPM feature called [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

In short, it's an organizational feature that allows organizations to group all of their packages under an official identifier.
From [the official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope):

> Scopes are a way of grouping related packages together, and also affect a few things about the way npm treats the package.
>
> Each npm user/organization has their own scope, and only you can add packages in your scope. This means you don't have to worry about someone taking your package name ahead of you. Thus it is also a good way to signal official packages for organizations.

There are some small tweaks in the way NPM handles scoped packages, for example, in `node_modules`, a directory is created for a scope, and all packages with that scope are stored in that directory. In almost all cases though, you can treat scoped packages identically to non-scoped packages.

Comment: sorry for stealing some of your upvotes, your answer is very good